# How to apply normal-mode mapping to all search pattern hits?

Tags: vim

Let's say I have the following normal-mode mapping in my `.vimrc`:

`nnoremap <Leader>Sc ciw{{c1::<C-r>"}}<Esc>`

Essentially this surrounds a word with braces and a prefix.

How can I apply this mapping to all search results? E.g.

```
PATTERN is in a line that can contain many PATTERN,
and another PATTERN here
```

would apply the mapping `<Leader>Sc` to all occurrences of `PATTERN`.

Closest I got was `:g//normal n\Sc`. `PATTERN` is in my search "buffer" and my leader is `\`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:g` allows you to do something on matched **lines**. Not occurrence. So if you want to apply your mapping on all `PATTERN`s, you can record macro, with `/ or ?` and `n` to navigate to next occurrence.

Actually, I think your mapping may handy when you are typing or do with a few cases. If you want to do the transformation on whole buffer, why not use the `:s` command? E.g.

```
:%s/\<PATTERN\>/{{c1::&}}/g
```

pretty easy and straightforward, isn't it? If you need this more you can make a mapping or write a little function to do that.